# OLS with ARMA errors, tip or two

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, arima, least-squares, econometrics

I need a tip or two.

I am performing OLS with dynamic factors (4x1 factors each representing a PANEL of 24 series, hence 4 time series).

My OLS has autocorrelation in the error so I want to use OLS with ARIMA errors, therefore I model my initial error and the only model that I have found that kills the autocorrelation is ARMA(3,7).

AR(1) does, OK job but I have some significant residuals in lag 4 and few later lags and everything else makes it worse until ARMA(3,7) which make the error 100% white noise (not a single value with significant Q-statistic).

My concern is that ARMA(3,7) model is crazy complex.. what does MA(7) even mean of the OLS error, I have no explanation behind it.

Should I perform a OLS with AR(1) errors even thought it is not perfect (DW statistic is around 2.1) or should I go for OLS with ARMA(3,7) errors which makes the regression perfect?

Any tips? Thanks :)

Comment: It sounds to me that there may be deterministic structure in the residuals ( pulses,level shifts,seasonal pulses) or an error variance that is not constant. Post your data in a csv file and I will try and help.

Comment: Hi IrishStat, I have filtered the original series for deterministics (but not for outliers).

How would advice me to check the residual structure for pulses, level shifts, etc.?

Comment: tsoutliers my be useful  but I am not sure. I apologize for the deletion of my answer as someone didn't  recognize that I had actually answered your question. Do you agree ?

Comment: I just checked my series and I can identify very strong weekly seasonality (every 7 days). I guess that causes the funky ARMA(3,7).

Weird thing is that, when I take diff(x,7) the seasonality still stays in the data.

Comment: your findings based upon my answer suggest that you add 6 seasonal dummies (6 seasonl pulses) ARiMA doesn't fix determnistic effects

Comment: Yep but that's the weird part, when I add them to the original OLS (the one that needs fixing) the dummies are not significant.

Then I take the error from the OLS and model an ARIMA structure to it and in the error itself I do not have weekly seasonality but in the individual series in the PACF it picks regularly on the 7th + lag.

I guess its very hard to advice without seeing the data. I will ask tomorrow if I can share it. Nevertheless, you have helped me a lot :) Thank you.

Comment: I would simply leave them in as they seem to absorb/fix the issue  the 6 indicators are being measure/tested on a 1 by 1 basis AND not collectively ...whereas the ar(7) is a global/composite efffect. I wonder when a series of very productive comments become an answer .... I guess only a moderator knows for sure !..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the issue. It was coming from stationary and non-stationary long-memory dependencies in my series.

After performing fractional differencing I was able to clean my model to perfection!

To estimate the differencing parameter I used Local Whittle methods.

Answer (score 2):

A collection of 4 useful comments should constitute an answer !

It sounds to me that there may be deterministic structure in the residuals ( pulses,level shifts,seasonal pulses) or an error variance that is not constant. Post your data in a csv file and I will try and help.

tsoutliers my be useful to test for deterministic structure.

I suggest that you add 6 seasonal dummies (6 seasonl pulses) AS ARIMA doesn't fix determnistic effects –

I would simply leave them in as they seem to absorb/fix the issue the 6 indicators are being measure/tested on a 1 by 1 basis AND not collectively ...whereas the ar(7) is a global/composite effect.